# Spring Data Elastic Search : Repository findById Returning Not Found

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to setup a Spring Data Elastic Project. Here is my document...

```
{
  "_index": "_idx1",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "440986688",
  "_version": 9,
  "_seq_no": 22175768,
  "_primary_term": 25,
  "found": true,
  "_source": {
    "dto": {
      "evidencePath": "path",
      "disclosurePath": "dPath",
      "allowedCommands": [],
      "actionText": "View - No action required",
      "closedNokReason": null,
      "closedNokComment": null,
      "evidenceDocuments": [
        {
          "identifier": "7355580062",
          "purpose": "COMMENT",
          "description": "Task submitted",
          "date": "2022/01/20 15:57:54",
          "dateISO": null,
          "provider": "Andrew",
          "contentStreamMimeType": "v_comment",
          "contentStreamLength": 14,
          "fileName": "comment_29160_1893869507.txt",
          "downloader": null,
          "downloaded": null,
          "wfdId": null,
          "draft": false,
          "controlOwner": null,
          "controlEmail": null,
          "controlProvisionId": null,
          "type": "COMMENT"
        }
       
      ],
      "referenceDocuments": [
       
      ],
     
      "message": null,
      "type": "Dash",
      "owner": "Andrew "
    },
    "id": 440986688,    
    "guiKey": "ap_apr_review_",
    "followupAllowed": false,
    "lastFollowup": null,
    "consolidatedMetric": "Review",
    "riskCategory": "Unassigned",
    "disclosureData": true,
    "disclosureDataActionText": "This  is submitted. ",
    "disclosureDataRows": [
      {
        "identifier": "4290018.00001",
        "evProvProcessId": "440986688",       
        "usPersonEmployee": "Yes"
      }
    ],
    "disclosureDataEnrichments": true,
    "ftdDelegateEmails": null,
    "ftdOwnerEmails": null,
    "reviewRequired": true,
    "gateDate": 1645814815901,
    "wspNumber": null,
    "wspBook": null,
    "wspSubBook": null,
    "other": {},
    "actionType": "FYI",
    "actionTypes": [],
    "allowedActions": [],
    "action": false,
    "actionText": "View - No action required",
    "wfdId": 111964,
    "message": ""
  }
}
```

Here is my ma document mapping...

```
@Document(indexName = "_idx1")
public class TaskBean {
    @Field(type = FieldType.Nested)
    private DtoBean dto;
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String wsp;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String wspId;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String control;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String evProvComment;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String reason;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String delegate;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String delegateEmail;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String delegationType;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String delegateId;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String owner;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String ownerEmail;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String ownerUBR;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private List<String> wspApplicability;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String commit;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String templateFiles;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String alertText;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String guiKey;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String followupAllowed;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String lastFollowup;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String consolidatedMetric;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String riskCategory;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String disclosureData;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String disclosureDataActionText;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Nested)
    private List<DisclosureRow> disclosureDataRows;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String disclosureDataEnrichments;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String ftdDelegateEmails;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String ftdOwnerEmails;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String reviewRequired;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String gateDate;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String wspNumber;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String wspBook;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String wspSubBook;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String other;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String actionType;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private List<String> actionTypes;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private List<String> allowedActions;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String action;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String actionText;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String wfdId;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String message;

}
```

My configuration class....

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.mi.repository")
public class ReactiveRestClientConfig  {

    
    
    @Value("${elasticsearch.host}")
    private String EsHost;
    
    @Value("${elasticsearch.port}")
    private int EsPort;
    
    @Value("${elasticsearch.user}")
    private String user;

    @Value("${elasticsearch.password}")
    private String password;
    
    
     @Bean
        public RestHighLevelClient client() {
         //System.out.println(EsHost);
         InetSocketAddress proxyAddress = null;
         try {
              proxyAddress =  new InetSocketAddress( InetAddress.getByName(EsHost), EsPort) ;
         }catch(Exception e) {
             
         }
            ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration 
                = ClientConfiguration.builder()
                        .connectedTo(proxyAddress)                                                                   
                        .withConnectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(50))                            
                        .withSocketTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(50))
                        .withBasicAuth(EsUser, EsPassword)          
                        .build();

            return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
        }

        @Bean
        public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() {
            return new ElasticsearchRestTemplate(client());
        }
    
     
    }
```

And finally, Service class...

```
@Component
public class TaskService {
    @Autowired
    private  TaskBeanRepository taskBeanRepository;
    
    public TaskBean findById(String id) {
        Optional<TaskBean> taskBean = taskBeanRepository.findById(id);
        if(taskBean.isPresent()) {
            return taskBean.get();
        }
        return  null;
    }
}
```

I have created a controller and calling this method through REST. Even after passing correct Id 440986688 to this method it is returning 404 not found. Any issue with my mapping?

Comment: With a 404 error, i would start to check es ip / connection. Check your client() first.

Comment: Thanks. Not receiving any error while connecting. is there any way to verify if it's actually connecting?

Comment: You cant get any information while debuging?

Comment: please add DEBUG Log on org.springframework package, this will give more details 

  <logger name="org.springframework" level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="GLOBAL_FILE" />
  </logger>

Comment: you don't show the most important part: the controller. 404 means that the controller method is not found. If the entity is not found you return null which should return as 200 with a "null" body. Or do you have any mapping of null to response code 404?

Comment: Thanks  P.J.Meisch! Seems I was barking on a wrong tree. REST URL had an issue. Sometimes we overlook the easy solution.  Thanks a ton!!!